# find the div with largest left property

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code:

```
var divWithTopLeft = null;
var maxLeft = 0;
$('.place').each(function(){
    left = this.style.left.replace('px','');
    if(left > maxLeft )
    {
         maxLeft = left;
         divWithTopLeft = this;
    }   
});
alert(divWithTopLeft.style.left);
```

But, it's work not properly. For my makrup it returns `85`. But, there are divs with 220 and more. Can you explain me why?
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UAYWD/1/)
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert them to a number first:

```
var left = parseInt(this.style.left, 10);
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UAYWD/2/